# Issue while assigning UITextView frame to CATextLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitextview, catextlayer

I'm retrieving subviews(`UITextView`) from the `UIImageView` and with the content of the `UITextView` I'm creating `CATextLayer` to add in the video file because I need to show each frame for a particular timeframe.
I was able to copy most of the attributes of `UITextView` except its frame.

```
for subview in tempImageView.subviews {          
    let textview : UITextView
    textview = subview as! UITextView
    let text = CATextLayer()
    text.frame = textview.frame
    print(text.frame)
    text.string = textview.text
    text.font = textview.font
    text.foregroundColor = textview.textColor?.cgColor 
    text.backgroundColor = textview.backgroundColor?.cgColor
    text.displayIfNeeded()
    text.beginTime = 3
    text.duration = 2    
    parentlayer.addSublayer(text)                
}
```

Comment: Use `for case let subview as UITextView in tempImageView.subviews {`